# How to read variables from locals in Swig custom tag/filter?

Tags: internationalization, swig-template

I'm trying to build i18n module for my app. Since I'm using swig I would prefer to create custom tag "trans" for that so translations result could be cached.

I'm using Express.js 4 as base for my app.

How can I read variable from request inside custom tag or filter? I have no idea how to read them (especially inside filters). I can't even access variables I pass to template. For example:

```
swig template index.swig
-------------------------------
{% trans %}this is sparta{% endtrans %}
{% trans "fr" %}this is sparta{% endtrans %}
-------------------------------
```

I can make line 2 works. I pass locale for "trans" and in my code replace text passed by user from a French translation.

But I don't want to pass locale to each and every trans tag. I would like to do something like that:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.locale = req.session.user.getLocale();
}
// now view should have locale variable
// and trans should use it to pick right translation from the table
{% trans %}this is sparta{% endtrans %}
```

Can anyone provide a tutorial or an explanation? Documentation for that part of swig is non existent. The problem is that each user can have different language so lang code is picked per request and I should have access to that inside swig custom tag.

Answer (score 1):

The template automatically reads locals from both `app.local` and `res.local`. Therefore, as noted, you could add middleware to set the locals on the response as follows:

```
app.use(function (req,res,next) { 
    res.locals.locale = req.session.user.getLocale();
    next();
});
```

This would expose `locale` as a global inside of your view.